# I can't insert data into my database from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

My data is not inserting into the database and I don't know why, everything is working fine. Even if I enter data directly into database, it shows up on the web page, but when I want to enter my data through the web page, it does not produce any response and data remains the same (data is not entered).

This is my controller :

```
// GET: Hostel/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
     return View();
}

// POST: Hostel/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Hostel collection)
{
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            List<object> list = new List<object>();
            list.Add(collection.H_Name);
            list.Add(collection.H_Phone);
            list.Add(collection.H_Description);
            list.Add(collection.H_TotalBedrooms);
            list.Add(collection.H_WifiCharges);
            list.Add(collection.H_SecurityCharges);
            list.Add(collection.H_MonthyRent);
            list.Add(collection.H_Image);
            list.Add(collection.H_Avaliablity);

            object[] listItems = list.ToArray();
            int cmnd = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into Hostel (H_Name, H_Phone, H_Description, H_TotalBedrooms, H_WifiCharges, H_SecurityCharges, H_MonthyRent, H_Image, H_Avaliablity) values (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9)", listItems);

            if(cmnd > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.msg = "User Added";
            }

            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass 10 parameters (@p0 to @p9) when you only pass 9 values? Do you get to the line `ViewBag.msg = "User Added";` or is that skipped?

Comment: Security alert: you should read up on [sql-injection](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @oerkelens yes brother , it is always skipped i don't know why . i have also corrected my stupid mistake of passing 9 elements in value parenthesis but still not working !

Comment: It looks like `db` is a DbContext. Consider `db.Hostels.Add(collection); db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes it is my model class object and iam clearly using same object to view list of data through database and it works but someone through debugging my query is not working i dont know why !

Comment: Try following @HenkHolterman 's suggestion. You are manually doing what Entity Framework can do for you very well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thankyou brother ! your'e life saver . I was dealing with this error for 3 days i cant find this small ambiguity . it finally worked . Thanks for help, much appreciated !

Comment: as i posted my own answer by solving the problem .Actually i used Entity Framework as HenkHolterman said and it solved my problem . And thanks for editing my question as you can see iam new here :P @TomTom

Comment: @TomTom then can you help me brother , how to deliver answer ? because im new here .

Comment: Start by reading the site rules and - common sense for ap rogrammer that is not new to programming at all (like day one).

Comment: @TomTom thanks brother.

Comment: Actually your self-answer wasn't a bad idea. Remove all the `list` code and undelete it. Don't worry about a -1 vote.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks brother , and yeah i was worried about that -1 in start but still main point is learning .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// POST: Hostel/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Hostel collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            //simply remove query and let entity framework to help you with that 
            db.Hostels.Add(collection);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```